# How can i select a folder inside tomcat to upload an image

Tags: java, tomcat, primefaces, server

I'm using Primefaces to upload images to tomcat 
through `<p:fileUpload/>`

I'm uploading in this folder : `C:\NEW WORK\sicweb\src\main\webapp\resources\images`

But when I put my application on a server, I can't put this way. How can I select a folder through a relative path or something like that

Or put inside `C:\java\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\sicweb` ?

This is my class :

```
public class UploadLogoOrgaoControle implements Serializable {

    public static String name = "";
    private String caminhoCarregado = "";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {    
        String path = "C:\\NEW WORK\\sicweb\\src\\main\\webapp\\resources\\images\\";
        name = event.getFile().getFileName();

        File file = new File(path + name);
        caminhoCarregado = "/sicweb/resources/images/" + name;

        InputStream is = event.getFile().getInputstream();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
        int len;

        while ((len = is.read(buf)) > 0)
            out.write(buf, 0, len);

        is.close();
        out.close();
    }

    public String getCaminhoCarregado() {
        return caminhoCarregado;
    }

    public void setCaminhoCarregado(String caminhoCarregado) {
        this.caminhoCarregado = caminhoCarregado;
    }
}
```

Comment: About the LAST thing you want to do is upload data to within your Tomcat directory.  One mistake and you could allow an attacker to completely take control of your web server.

Comment: Well, thanks for that, i didn't know... So, how can i do this?

Comment: By using an absolute path